# Pass Json to javascript in specific format to render the chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am working on chart library,

I have json format, which will be coming from server, year and month format

```
{
"id": 1,
"name": "name1",
"present": "18",
"target": "18",
"status": "yellow"
}
```

Now I need to pass `present` and `target` values in a array format.

the data must be passed or parsed like below.

How to do I do this in javascript and jquery?

I tried all the available solutions, since I am new to the javascript world!

**Expected result**

```
var legendsText = [["present name1","target name1"]],
jsonFormat = [[18, 18],[15,18],[36, 18]];
```

**FIDDLE**

This is the fiddle our friend **Eli Gassert** has created, it is the closeset one

**[http://http://jsfiddle.net/Yq3DW/126/](http://jsfiddle.net/Yq3DW/126/)**

but it is loading only present values of all 3 months

i want present and target values of each name.

**For example**

**name1** link clicked, chart should load name1 present and target for all 3 months.

**name2** link clicked, chart should load name2 present and target for all 3 months.

**name3** link clicked, chart should load name3 present and target for all 3 months.

My JSON format which is coming dynamically from server

```
data={
  "perspective": "something",
  "year": "2014",
  "measures": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "some name",
      "target": "200",
      "responsiblePerson": null
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "some name",
      "target": "100",
      "responsiblePerson": null
    }
  ],
  "values": {
    "jan": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "name1",
        "present": "18",
        "target": "18",
        "status": "yellow"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "name2",
        "present": "21",
        "target": "22",
        "status": "red"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "name3",
        "present": "50",
        "target": "50",
        "status": "yellow"
      }
    ],
    "feb": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "name1",
        "present": "18",
        "target": "18",
        "status": "yellow"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "name2",
        "present": "21",
        "target": "22",
        "status": "red"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "name3",
        "present": "50",
        "target": "50",
        "status": "yellow"
      }
    ],
    "mar": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "name1",
        "present": "18",
        "target": "18",
        "status": "yellow"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "name2",
        "present": "22",
        "target": "22",
        "status": "yellow"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "name3",
        "present": "52",
        "target": "50",
        "status": "yellow"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="chart"></div>
```

JS

```
    var legendsText = [];
for(var i = 0; i != data.measures.length; ++i)
    legendsText.push(data.measures[i].name);

legendsText = [legendsText];

var rows = [];

for(var i in data.values)
{
    var row = []

    for(var j = 0; j != data.values[i].length; ++j)
    {
        row.push(data.values[i][j].present);
    }

    rows.push(row);
}

rows = legendsText.concat(rows.sort(function (a, b) {  }));
console.log(rows);
var chart = c3.generate({
bindto: '#chart',
data: {
rows: rows,
type: 'bar',
}
});
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is a tough one, I believe you could benefit from using underscorejs

Comment: @  docodemore - i dont know underscorejs. kindly tell me if you have any solution. Please check this fiddle, which i have created. http://jsfiddle.net/Yq3DW/99/. if it helps??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an updated fiddle that transforms your data to the results: http://jsfiddle.net/Yq3DW/119/

Key aspects:
Your Legend Text can be gotten dynamically from your `measures` data. The format for the legendsText is an "array of arrays" so that's why I wrap it in `[...]` at the end of the loop.

```
var legendsText = [];
for(var i = 0; i != data.measures.length; ++i)
    legendsText.push(data.measures[i].name);

legendsText = [legendsText];
```

Your rows can be gotten from your "values" data. But because it's not an array, like `measures` you need to use a `for each` loop instead of `for` loop:

```
var rows = [];

for(var i in data.values)
{
    var row = []

    for(var j = 0; j != data.values[i].length; ++j)
    {
        row.push(data.values[i][j].present);
    }

    rows.push(row);
}
```

**EDIT**: Updated question. To show just one label's worth of data but show both values for that data, and give nice labels: http://jsfiddle.net/Yq3DW/130/

The key here:

1. Switch to columns instead of rows, allowing one "row" of data to stand-in for the label indexer
2. Only add the data if the name in the value data matches the name you're searching for (had to update your data JSON so the names matched)
3. Had to use a 'tick' formatter to format the labels from 1-3 to jan, feb, mar. You can further customize it by using upper case/proper case conversions. That is outside the scope of this question and I'm not including it here. If you need further formatting, search for an answer first and if you can't find it, start a new Q.
4. Display a dynamic list of links to click that calls your `loadData` function to change the data in the chart between the various measure names

HTML:

```
<ul id="links"></ul>

<div id="chart"></div>
```

JS:

```
var $links = $('#links');
$links.html('');

for(var i = 0; i != data.measures.length; ++i)
{
    (function()
     {
        var name = data.measures[i].name;

        $('<li></li>')
            .text(data.measures[i].name)
            .click(function() { loadData(name); })
            .appendTo($links);
     })();

    // legendsText.push(data.measures[i].name);
}

function loadData(name)
{
    //var legendsText = [ ["present", "target"] ];
    var columns = [ ["labels"], [ "present" ], [ "target" ]];
    var labels = [];
    for(var i in data.values)
    {
        var row = []

        for(var j = 0; j != data.values[i].length; ++j)
        {
            if(data.values[i][j].name == name)
            {
                labels.push(i);
                columns[0].push(labels.length);


                columns[1].push(data.values[i][j].present);
                columns[2].push(data.values[i][j].target);
            }
        }

        //rows.push(row);
    }

    console.log(columns);

    //rows = legendsText.concat(rows.sort(function (a, b) {  }));
    var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#chart',
    data: {
        x: 'labels',
    columns: columns,
    type: 'bar',
    },
    axis: {
        x: {
            tick:  {
                format: function(index) { return labels[index-1]; }
            }
        }
    }
    });
}
```

Comment: thank you for this, sorry if i am not explained properly, `i need name1 in 3 months with present and target. means i have a name1 Link outside the chart. if user clicks link, chart should load only name1 present and target.`

Comment: i have updated the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Yq3DW/122/, if name1 link clicked, chart should load name1 present and target. please help me.

Comment: Edited according to your updated Q. If this is still not correct, you should be able to solve your needs with a combination of the two solutions I put forth. I would highly recommend NOT updating your question again and asking for further edits unless my answer is completely off basis for what you need. Edits like that can get out of control. If this gets you the gist of what you're looking for, I recommend you marking it as the answer for others.

Comment: Dude, you are a saint. From 15 days i am trying to solve this. it is absolutely perferct solution which i was looking. Thank you. i really appreciate it.